# asp.net webconfig configuration for authentication or login required webserver

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I want to run a asp.net website on two different servers. On the first server the login is handled just by windows login. That works well. But on the other server I need to register and login with a userID and a password. Maybe I`m using the wrong connection setting?

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="Password=***;Persist Security Info=true;User id=***-Example;Initial Catalog=AN-Example;Data Source=***.**.**.***"/>
```

The configuration above is for the first server which work's fine. I have changed only the IP-Adress.
Somebody had the same task already?

Edit

I also use following authentication mode:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

When trying to open the site i get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/MY/Site' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCellCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell'. 'asp:TextBox' is of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'.

Source Error: 


Line 170:                   </td> 
Line 171:                    <td align="left"; class="style19">
Line 172:                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbCustomer" runat="server" 
Line 173:                            Text="" ValidationGroup="Size" Visible = 'false' Width="100%" TabIndex="4" ></asp:TextBox>
Line 174:                   </td>

Source File: /My/Site/default.aspx    Line: 172
```

Could it be caused by different country/unicode setting? The first server is from Germany the second from USA

Edit

I'm not sure but i think it's something with the database what cause the error I will look on it

Comment: So what happens when you try to get into the second server? any error?

Comment: yes i get a error message but i makes no sense, wait i will post it too

Answer (score 0):

```
<td align="left"; class="style19">
```

Contains a semicolon. Should be:

```
<td align="left" class="style19">
```

The error says that the textbox is not a valid child of a HtmlTableCellCollection. My guess would be that it cannot understand the td tag with the semicolon in it.

Comment: thank you, I will try it and give a response tomorrow